# SQL Server Unique Values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server view that I have created that shows a list of companies and if they have a salesperson assigned, then it will be included, otherwise the value for salesperson will be blank.

When I run the query against this view, for the companies that have a salesperson assigned, I am getting 2 records, 1 with a blank Salesperson and another with the salesperson value.

What I am trying to get is a list with unique values for the company and if they have a salesperson assigned, then it would include that value and if the company doesn't have one, then the salesperson would be left blank.

The first table below shows what my current output is giving me. The 2nd table below shows an example of what I am trying to get. Any help is appreciated.

---

e.g.

**Current Result**

```
CustNO Company              SalesPerson
ACM1   Acme Corp 
ACM1   Acme Corp            Bugs Bunny
ABC1   ABC Company  
SSP1   Spacely Sprockets  
SSP1   Spacely Sprockets    Daffy Duck
SPN1   Springfield Nuclear
SPN1   Springfield Nuclear  Porky Pig
```

**Expected Result**

```
CustNO Company              SalesPerson
ACM1   Acme Corp            Bugs Bunny
ABC1   ABC Company
SSP1   Spacely Sprockets    Daffy Duck
SPN1   Springfield Nuclear  Porky Pig
```

Here is the SQL statement for the View, not sure if it helps or not:

```
    Create View SalesList as (
    select distinct T1.CUSTNO as 'CustNo',        
           T1.COMPNAME as 'Company', 
           T1.SALESCODE as 'SalesID',               
           T2.EMPLNAME as 'Salesperson',       
           case 
              when T2.STATUS = 0 then 'Inactive'
              when T2.STATUS = 1 then 'Active'
           end as 'SalesStatus',
           T2.SALESRATE as 'CommissionPct', 
           case 
              when T3.optfield = 'PARTNERAGENT' THEN T3.VALUE
              else ''
           end as 'AgentCode' , 
           case 
              when T3.OPTFIELD = 'PARTNERAGENT' THEN T4.VDESC
              else ''
           end as 'AgentName' 
    from Table1 as T1  
    left join Table2 as T2 on T1.SALESCODE = T2.SALESCODE
    left join Table3 as T3 on T1.CUSTNO = T3.CUSTNO
    left join Table4 as T4 on T3.VALUE = T4.VALUE
    where T2.EMPLOYEECD = 'PARTNER')
```

Hopefully this provides more information to be able to provide feedback.  Thank you.

Comment: could you please share your view's definition with us?

Comment: `When I run the query against this view` please provide "the query" when asking your question, it is important to do this otherwise you are very likely to be downvoted, also you can use fixed width text to demonstrate your results and desired outcome instead of forcing us to click on images. *examples added to question*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without schema detail it's hard to give you an answer. Based on the screen caps provided I'll assume you're trying to perform aggregation, with non-empty `Sales Person` returned if any. As a trick, built-in function `MAX` may help.

```
SELECT
    CustNo, Company, MAX("Sales Person") AS "Sales Person"
FROM
    tableA
GROUP BY CustNo, Company
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this option!!!  This trick actually worked exactly how i needed it to work and gave me the output i needed for my script.  Sincerely appreciate the help.

Comment: No worries @R.White. Would you please also accept the answer, so others would be clear it's a solution to the question.